# Change passed argument

Tags: c#

I have this scenario:

```
private bool form_1_Enabled = true;

private new Dictionary<string,bool> dict = new Dictionary<string,bool>()
{
   { 'is_form_1_enabled',  this.form_1_Enabled }
};    

for(var i in dict)
{
    if (i.Value == true)
    {
        i.Value = false;   // this should change form_1_Enabled
    }
}
```

so, the idea is to change the passed property.
Is something like that possible?

The only solution i've found was:

```
(dynamic)this.GetType().GetProperty(i.Value).GetValue(this, null) = false;
```

Comment: What's `i.Value == false;` supposed to do? Note that there's nothing like a "global variable" in c#

Comment: Are you hoping that changing `i.Value` change `form_1_Enabled` as well?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto i ask that exactly. how to achieve that.

Comment: What do you mean by `this` in the code comment? Do you just want to assign a different value to the boolean ie: `i.Value = false;` (*notice = is used for assignment, == is an equality check*).

Comment: @Igor thanks, my bad.. yes, i ask how to change the property from that loop..

Comment: You would need to use reflection or add a custom call back using an `Action` or `Delegate`.

Comment: That said as soon as you have to copy and maintain duplicate state you should think a different solution. Keeping state in sync is expensive and error prone. A better solution might be to only use the dictionary and have other code access that directly or indirectly (by indirect I mean you could have a helper function that returns a value based on some parameter).

Comment: can't you just use something like a `all_Disabled` flag?

Comment: Why does it have to be done that ugly way? Can you do this instead? `private bool form_1_Enabled { get { return dict["is_form_1_enabled"]; } }` BTW, you are using `'` for a string, which of course is an error.

Comment: @Andrew no, i use dynamic amount of members

Comment: You need to provide more context to find a good solution. I think we are just seeing the tip of the iceberg.

Answer (score 1):

As soon as you have to copy and maintain duplicate state you should think a different solution. Keeping state in sync is expensive and error prone.

Some alternatives (in no particular order)

Use the dictionary and have other code access that directly or indirectly (*by indirect I mean you could have a helper function that returns a value based on some parameter*).

---

Seems your code uses the dictionary only to loop through the private variables and set their value. Instead of a dictionary use reflection on the instance to find all private fields instances of type boolean, with additional checks as necessary like on name or an attribute marker, and (re)set the value that way.

Example:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;


public void Reset()
{
    foreach (var field in this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        .Where(x=>x.Name.EndsWith("Enabled", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && x.FieldType == typeof(bool)))
    {
        field.SetValue(this, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in c# a bool is a value type it is always copied by value. If you want to copy it by reference you could write a wrapper for the value type

```
class A
{
    private BoolWrapper form_1_Enabled = new BoolWrapper(true);

    private new Dictionary<string, BoolWrapper> dict;
    public A()
    {
        dict = new Dictionary<string, BoolWrapper>() { { "is_form_1_enabled", form_1_Enabled }, };
        foreach (var i in dict)
        {
            if (i.Value.Value == true)
            {
                i.Value.Value = false;
            }
        }
    }

    public class BoolWrapper
    {
        public bool Value { get; set; }
        public BoolWrapper(bool value) { this.Value = value; }
    }
}
```